# Ruby/Regex Error: warning: character class has duplicated range

Tags: ruby, regex

Im trying to get this [Ruby code beautifier](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html) working and have hit on a problem to do with regular expressions that to be honest I just don't understand as my experience with them is extremely limited.

The error that Im getting is:

```
warning: character class has duplicated range: /.*=\s*<<-?\s*([_|\w]+).*/
```

Which points to this line:

```
here_doc_term = tline.sub(%r{.*=\s*<<-?\s*([_|\w]+).*},"\\1")
```

Could someone please be kind enough to point out what the issue is with this expression?

Thanks.

Comment: `\w` already includes `_`, maybe that's your problem.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thankyou, do you want to submit that as an answer so I mark it accepted?

Comment: Do you really mean to match a literal `|`? If not, then the `|` in the character class is detrimental, since it will match a literal `|`. Also, if you intend to match only the needed sequence, no need for the `.*` at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically this warning, tells you that a character class that you're using has some redundant pattern. I assume it points to the `[_|\w]`, as `\w` already contains underscores.

[This discussion](https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/252) might help understanding it more.

Comment: oh, someone already pointed that out in a comment, sorry, didn't see that.